# return colum name when has a value sql mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a poll with three options `A, B & C`

**table votes**

```
 id_poll id_voter value_A value_B value_C
    23      12      0       1       0
    23      11      1       0       0
```

Anytime I vote on an specific letter I insert the number 1 to its column and 0 to the others

**PROBLEM**

I want to return the column name of the voted letter (where 1 exists).

I was tthinking something like this

**SQL**

```
SELECT (¿?) as entry_selected 
FROM poll
WHERE (column_value=1?) AND id_voter='11'
```

I want to return `value_A`

Comment: Side note: I would recommend you don't store data like this. When you have to add a new option to your poll, you have to refactor the table.

Comment: So Instead...single column with different options right? `A, B,C,D,E...`

Comment: Right. Your table design only makes sense if they can choose multiple options. But even then, it would be better to just allow multiple rows with different votes.

Comment: Probably 5 tables: A poll table, a questions table, an options table, a table to tie questions to polls, and a table to tie options to questions. When you make a new poll, it goes into the poll table, If it has 5 questions, those go to the questions table. You insert entries in your xref table to tie those 5 questions to that poll. Then each question has 3 options, so those options go to the options table, and also into the table that ties options to questions. Using this, you could join to all tables and find what questions are on each poll and what options are available for each question

Comment: @dfundako your polls-questions and questions-options linking tables are overkill; it is unlikely that a question will be regularly reused for multiple polls, or an option reused for enough questions to make that worthwhile; questions need simply reference the poll they are a part of, and options reference the question they are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `case`:

```
select (case when value_a = 1 then 'value_a'
             when value_b = 1 then 'value_b'
             when value_c = 1 then 'value_c'
        end)
from poll
where 1 in (value_a, value_b, value_c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to hardcode the column names (unless someone else has a better solution), but you could do:

```
SELECT IF(value_a = 1, 'value_a', IF(value_b, 'value_b', IF(value_c, 'value_c', ''))) as entry_selected 
FROM poll
WHERE (value_a = 1 OR value_b = 1 OR value_c = 1) AND id_voter='11'
```

A better solution would be to change how your data is structured:

```
id_poll id_voter value
23      12       B     
23      11       A
```

Comment: I go for the second option (reestructuring the table), definitely